# How to load Laravel Middleware in Kernel.php conditionally?

Tags: laravel

I need the middleware to be loaded for local environments, but not production.
It's currently defined in app/Http/Kernel.php in the `$middleware` array.

Is it possible to check the environment there, and then use a ternary expression? Or are the environment variables not yet loaded? Using Laravel 5.8

Answer (score 1):

What about using a Service Provider to register that middleware instead of directly putting it in the global middleware stack, `$middleware`, in `app/Http/Kernel.php`?

You can have a Service Provider in the `boot` method register the middleware with the HTTP Kernel based on the conditions you need:

```
public function boot()
{
    if ($this->app->environment('local')) {
        $this->app->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class)
            ->pushMiddleware(\Some\Package\Middleware::class);
    }
}
```

You have the `pushMiddleware` or `prependMiddleware` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Just idea, you can set middleware groups in `kernel.php` like below

#### kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'local' => [
            // \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            // \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            // \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            // \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'dev' => [
            ...
        ],
    ];
```

#### RouteServiceProvider.php

Now you can set your local middlewares in RouteServiceProvider.

```
public function map()
    {
        if ($this->app->environment('local)) {
            Route::middleware('local')
                 ->namespace($this->namespace)
                 ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        }
    }
```

Not tested

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check environment inside your middleware. You don't need to tell Laravel to only load your middleware when in local, but you just need to tell your code, to only run when in local.

**FooMiddleware.php**

```php
class FooMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (app()->environment('local')) {
            // some stuff
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

If middleware is not yours, then you just need to extends that middleware or chain that middleware, then do like above. For example, when you only need to run `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize` in local, then:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize as Middleware;

class Authorize
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string  $ability
     * @param  array|null  ...$models
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $ability, ...$models)
    {
        if (app()->environment('local')) {
            // chain the middleware 
            return app(Middleware::class)->handle($request, function ($request) use ($next) {
                return $next($request);
            }, $ability, $models);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then, just replace in **Kernel.php** to your new middleware.

```php
/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    ...
    'can' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here what I ended up with to protect any dev or test servers. Works like a charm.

```
class TestMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
          if(env('APP_ENV') != 'production') {
            f(Request::getUser() != 'test'){
                return Response::make('Invalid credentials.', 401, $headers);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the constructor of the `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```
...

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;

...

 public function __construct(Application $app, Router $router)
    {
        if (env('APP_ENV', 'production') !== 'local') {
            $this->routeMiddleware['throttle'] =  \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class;
        } else {
            $this->routeMiddleware['throttle'] = \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequestsWithRedis::class;
        }

        parent::__construct($app, $router);
    }
```

And of course you can replace the `$this->routeMiddleware` with the relevant group accordingly or go further and use ternaries to shorten the code.

Comment: Funny this was the exact thing I wanted to conditionally load in Laravel :)